# How to use the TCL script to test the C language function on the embedded system?

Tags: c, embedded, tcl, swig

I want to test the C language function on the embedded system.
The topology is:
PC -------(console or telnet)------ Embedded system.

The testing script is running on PC, and call the C language function on the Embedded system.
I want to use the TCL script to test it.
I see a solution: Embed the TCL interpreter to embedded system run-time.

The test steps:

1. PC send the TCL script to embedded system.
2. The TCL interpreter that embed in embedded system parse the TCL script and run it to call C language function.

Q1: Does this is a feasible solution?

Q2: There are other possible solution (Must run TCL script on PC)?

Q3: Does need to embed SWIG on embedded system run-time?

Thanks.

Comment: As long as there's a way to invoke the function and see whether it succeeds or fails — an embedded Tcl interpreter is not the only way to do this; a little C program could do reasonably too — then there's no reason to put Tcl on the embedded system.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. Yes, it can use a little C program.  But this embedded system is a very very big system and in the growing. We expect to use an extensible interface to test it.  So we thought about the use of Tcl.

Answer (score 0):

Like many situations, the choice of where to partition things between processors depends upon many factors. Just because a system is embedded in its nature does not necessarily mean that embedded computer is not very powerful. I have done what you suggest, running a Tcl interpreter on an embedded system and using it to drive testing of the embedded application. But that was a long time ago, in the Tcl 7.x days. The current Tcl interpreter is quite large by embedded computer standards (although quite small by conventional computer standards). You might want to consider something like [Jim Tcl](http://jim.tcl.tk/index.html/doc/www/www/index.html) to obtain a smaller footprint. As Donal suggests, you really need only some small means in the embedded system to map a string you would send (presumably from a Tcl script running on your "PC") to invoke a function and return a string indicating the result. This is the technique I use in my embedded systems now, as it is much smaller and easier to implement than porting Tcl to my embedded environment. This arrangement still gives you considerable power, since you can use things such as `tcltest` to drive the test case, sending the command string to the embedded system, obtaining the result from the embedded system and comparing the obtained result with an expected one. With some up front design, the code in the embedded system that maps strings to function invocations and returns the result can be automatically generated from an textual interface specification (a la some swig-like concept but much simpler) to ease the task of adding more testable function interfaces in the embedded system. This is basically the strategy that I use now since my embedded system computers are small microcontrollers usually with less than 64K of memory. Over time you can build a powerful testing infrastructure.